# how to prevent data to reload when page refresh?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

In vue.js after getting data from backend.
I need the data to stay even the page is refresh.

supposed I click the login button and get the data of the user:
and if page refresh all data is gone.

```
onmounted is no good as it will not work because their is parameter the username and password,
```

how can i achieve this. please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some data on your page, then you need to load it from server. Every time you load your page after refresh, submit or navigating away.

There are many ways to achieve it. But without knowing your application setup and seeing your code we cannot provide you with any advice how you should do it.

Please provide the code of your attempt and the information about the backend.

Comment: is localstorage not good idea bro

Comment: Localstorage is good when you need some fixed one time updated data. But when you have realtime updated data then local storage is less quality effort for your module.